# Placing a variable within an inserted formula

Tags: excel, vba, formula

The loop is already in place, but I can't seem to get the syntax for replacing A2 with a correct variable.

```
For Each c In rng1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, c.Value) = 0 Then
        sh3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2) = c.Value
        sh3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(2).Formula = _
            "=INDEX(MatList!$D$13:$D$62,MATCH(A2,MatList!$A$13:$A$62,0))"
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace your formula from:

```
"=INDEX(MatList!$D$13:$D$62,MATCH(A2,MatList!$A$13:$A$62,0))"
```

To:

```
"=INDEX(MatList!$D$13:$D$62,MATCH(" & YourVariableName & ",MatList!$A$13:$A$62,0))"
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for that. getting closer. seems like i'm in a paradox now though the variable "x" has a value of 0 and 6 at the same time.
[curious](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2phfN.jpg)